# Max value of sub-list items

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for the optimal method to find the maximum value of sub-list items in a list.

Here is my O(n.m) implementation:

```
vector<int> movMax(const vector<int>& v, int span)
{
    span /= 2;

    vector<int> ret = v;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = std::max(0, i - span); j < std::min((int)v.size(), i + span + 1); j++)
        {
            ret[i] = std::max(ret[i], v[j]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 4, 3, 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 2 };

    v = movMax(v, 3);
    for (int x : v) cout << x << ' '; // 4 4 7 7 7 5 5 2
}
```

Comment: you need a queue for that which will track index and last max value and use it to replace one of for loops you have. Form one side of queue you will remove "old" items, from other to small items. AFAIR there is similar problem to solve on hackerrank. Is this hint enough? I wish avoid to provide full code (it will be better for you if you write this yourself).

Comment: What does "find the maximum value of sub-list items" mean? I don't understand why you go from `4, 3, 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 2` to `4 4 7 7 7 5 5 2`

Comment: he tries find a maximum for moving window of range of values. Windows size is `span`.

Comment: And your algorithm isn't `O(N^2)`, it is `O(v.size() * span)`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that.

@MarekR I can't get any better solution using queue (?)

It's also better for the solution to query any desired sub-list

Comment: What should happen if `span` value is even not odd? Window should cover more at front or beginning?

Comment: By using queue you will get `O(v.size())` complexity. So it is impossible to get better result (reading/printing data is `O(v.size())`).

Comment: Note that for even values of `span` your code fails for both interpretations: https://godbolt.org/z/441Ybj1Pb you are rounding up span to odd value.

Comment: Are you always scanning whole vector from begin to end or is there any random access pattern?

Comment: You should edit your question and better explain the problem that you're trying to solve. Your description is mostly meaningless to those of us who are not familiar with that exact problem. A more complete description of the problem usually leads to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that's O(N log M), where N is the size of the input, and M is the window.

We keep a track of the values within the window in-order, so adding or removing them is O(log M), and we do this for each element of v.

```
std::vector<int> movMax(const std::vector<int>& v, int window)
{
    int mid = window / 2;
    int size = v.size();
    
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(size);
    std::multiset<int> working_set;
    
    for (int i = -mid; i < size + mid; ++i) 
    {    
        if (i + mid < size) working_set.insert(v.at(i + mid));
        if (i >= 0 && i < size) result.push_back(*working_set.rbegin());
        if (i - mid >= 0) working_set.erase(working_set.find(v.at(i - mid)));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bc18d2762dfb126)

If window is allowed to be even, you need to account for which side it prefers.

Instead of defining one `mid`, you have `wide` and `narrow`:

```
int wide = window / 2;
int narrow = window - wide - 1;
```

Assuming window should span to front more:

```
for (int i = -narrow; i < size + wide; ++i) 
{    
    if (i + narrow < size) working_set.insert(v.at(i + narrow));
    if (i >= 0 && i < size) result.push_back(*working_set.rbegin());
    if (i - wide >= 0) working_set.erase(working_set.find(v.at(i - wide)));
}
```

Assuming window should span to back more:

```
for (int i = -wide; i < size + narrow; ++i) 
{    
    if (i + wide < size) working_set.insert(v.at(i + wide));
    if (i >= 0 && i < size) result.push_back(*working_set.rbegin());
    if (i - narrow >= 0) working_set.erase(working_set.find(v.at(i - narrow)));
}
```

[With tests on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c77cd5rEh)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Wvxsh9nG8

Comment: @MarekR I knew there was a relatively simple fix to the even window case, but didn't have time to figure it out yesterday

Comment: Note there is no specification how even `span` value should be treated. I've posted respective comment under question (no response so far). OPs code fails both possible cases, so this could not be concluded based on code.

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for the solution and the code. MATLAB movMax function is still much faster (so I guess there might be any better algorithm)